# What is the thing the boys could not eat?

Tags: lateral-thinking

There were $3$ BOYS living in a house with their father and mother.
 One day, they decided no matter what, they are going to eat ONE THING.
One of them said: "Today is **SUNDAY**, we can wake up late and take our time to eat that THING we were craving about".
As they were ready to get back to sleep, their mother yelled "You'd better wake up and clean that dirty room of yours".
They had no other choice but to obey their mother. It was 8AM when they started the chore.
After one hour , the room was clean and the drooling 3 boys thought it is time to eat that THING.
But their joy didn't last. The mother yelled again: "Have you finished your **HOMEWORK**?". They replied in the **NEGATIVE**.
"You better finished your HOMEWORK before your father gets back from the **FARM**".
Their homework was so hard that it took them four hours to finish.
Just in time, their father got back from the FARM to find the $3$ boys sobbing.
"What's the **MATTER**?" asked the father.
"We can not eat that THING anymore, ..."
What is the thing the $3$ boys wanted to badly eat?

Hint:

> The family lives in Japan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Breakfast. (Assuming one doesn't eat breakfast at 1 pm.)

Or to be more specific:

> Breakfast at the local restaurant (as they normally start serving lunch/brunch at noon).

After the hint about it being in Japan.

> Breakfast is in Japanese literally called "Morning Meal". You wouldn't consider 1 pm as a morning (at least not when greeting people), thus still: Breakfast

Comment: 'Morning' can mean different things in different cultures, e.g. in Italy 'morning' doesn't end until around 2pm. Could it still be 'morning meal' in Japanese if you eat it at 1pm?

Comment: @randal'thor: True, and this might not be the answer OP had in mind. _But_ when greeting people in Japan it seems people goes from Good morning (Ohaiyou Gozaimasu) to Hello (Konnichiwa) around noon. After noon, one says Good Afternoon (Konbanwa).

Comment: This a correct answer. In japan, from 12pm it is lunch time.

Answer (score 3):

> Ice.  It is freezing at night, they had put syrup on the window-sill overnight.  But now it is all melted.
>
>  Or maybe it was a dessert made of fresh snow and syrup.

Answer (score 2):

The

> [Body of Christ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacramental_bread), distributed on sunday morning, among the people in the church.

Comment: Not many Christians in Japan...

Comment: Not that hint or title when I wrote my answer. But still, it *could* be a solution

Answer (score 1):

> the boys wanted to sleep.

although i don't know japanese, but i think it is related

> that in japanese they say 'i eat sleep' or something.

Comment: +1 This could well be it. I was thinking it must be something to do with 'eat' in a metaphorical sense.

Comment: I've never heard of any phrases like "I eat sleep" - where did you hear this from?

Comment: i did say i don't know japanese. i meant along the lines as written by rand al'thor. metaphorical sense or something.